# Why are complete question deviations, making answers effectively meaningless, allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, rejected-edits

I recently suggested edits that roll back their OP's complete replacement of the initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18383091) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18390443). However, they are *rejected*. Why are they rejected? Are we allowed to keep changing our questions?

Comment: They look like decent improvements to me that don't actually change the question.  Hard to disagree with the reviewers.  Adding a snippet when it becomes clear that contributors don't see the problem: good.  Editing a heavily downvoted question: good.  Submitting the same edit proposal when it was rejected before: bad.  It is not a lottery.

Comment: @HansPassant I can maybe follow you with the first question even though the OP added an answer into their own question which is not where it should be (I would have left the "Edit: ..." part though). However, the second one is completely changing the question from "How do I change the drawing color?" to "How can I draw random points on the canvas wherever I move the mouse?"

Comment: @Nae: Did you really roll-back edits or did you simply edit these things out? At least for the first question you edit description could have been clearer. The question did not change at all in this case. What you did was removing an answer from the question (and you should have stated that instead).

Comment: @BDL Well, I selected the last edit before the very last and sent edit.

Comment: @HansPassant In the first question what OP edited has nothing to do with his initial question. OP was having an issue with place method, he got an answer. I further commented on that OP may have difficulties showing an image later, and OP then edited their question mentioning _this_ as the issue and its solution as the _solution_. I thought it was misleading so I suggested roll-back edit.

Comment: @HansPassant Also note that second question had its minuses 2 edits before that mostly. Not sure if you are able to see that though. See [the question's initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48038473/edit/27764494-3952-44c4-96e0-96ba0c0c3a83).

Comment: I guess it is a problem with editing from an old revision. In the review it looks like *you* are changing the question completely. Side-note: You really shouldn't try to reapply edits that have already been rejected.

Comment: @BDL It _does_ look like a [lottery](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18392328) though. Why shouldn't I, any related meta posts?

Comment: Another 59 rep and you won't have to participate in the lottery anyway.

Comment: Your successful edit attempt probably had a better edit summary as it makes clear that it was reversing a change invalidating an existing answer. The edited question is asking something entirely different and should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Note that now that you have over 2K rep, you should be able to use the actual rollback links to remove damaging edits instead of manually editing the question back to its previous state.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why are complete question deviations, making answers effectively meaningless, allowed?

I take you to mean "allowed" in the sense that the rejection of your edits allowed such changes as you ask about to persist, as opposed to "allowed" in the sense that the community finds the behavior you describe to be acceptable, which it does not.

Edit reviewers don't see the whole edit history, only the one edit under review, and it isn't even marked as a rollback in the way that it is in the revision history.  It is therefore essential for your edit comment to be as clear as possible about the reason for the change.  In rolling back such a change, you take the risk that your edit will be interpreted as just such a change as you are (rightfully) objecting to.

Even with a good edit comment, however, (and I'd rate yours as so-so) reviewers sometimes screw up, and they are more likely to do so in a case such as those we're discussing.  That's just the nature of the system.  In the event that you think a good edit was rejected on account of the reviewers misunderstanding its nature, you do have the alternative of mod-flagging the question and explaining the situation.  I would use that option very sparingly if I were you, however.

With that said, I am not convinced that the reviewers got these wrong, at least the first.  That edit appears to be a bit of an overreach to me -- you removed some commentary that should have stayed.  The other edit looks good to me in context.

Comment: While I agree with this, for the most part, I was unaware of the fact that my edits were not marked as roll-backs, thus I wasn't concerned all that much with emphasizing the edit's roll-back nature, as I literally picked an old revision and pressed the edit button.

Answer (score -11):

Based on [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361267/why-are-complete-question-deviation-making-answers-effectively-meaningless-is?noredirect=1#comment543694_361267):

In the reviews, it looks like *you*(OP of this meta post) are the one changing the question completely.

Comment: Who is "you"???

Comment: Ah, the old "post a self-answer written in the second person and look incredibly silly in the process."

Comment: OP has literally pasted one of the comments as an answer